# Permission denied when authenticating pod to external vault service running on gke

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, hashicorp-vault

GKE version - 1.14
Currently I have two private gke cluster ( Vault cluster and app cluster)

Getting following errors:

```
vault errors -
auth.kubernetes.auth_kubernetes_b0f01fa6: login unauthorized due to: Post "https://10.V.V.194:443/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews": dial tcp `10.V.V.194`:443: i/o timeout
```

-> where

```
10.V.V.194 -- is master IP address (no https://) via `kubectl cluster-info
```

Application pod logs

```
    * permission denied" backoff=1.324573453
2020-10-12T14:39:46.421Z [INFO]  auth.handler: authenticating
2020-10-12T14:40:16.427Z [ERROR] auth.handler: error authenticating: error="Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://10.LB.LB.38:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login
Code: 403. Errors:

* permission denied" backoff=2.798763368
```

-> Where

```
http://10.LB.LB.38:8200 is Internal LB IP
```

Vault setup

```
    NAME   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                         
test-vault  LoadBalancer   240.130.0.59   10.LB.LB.38   8200:32105/TCP,8201:31147/TCP
```

How is K8s auth methods enable

```
    $ export VAULT_SA_NAME=$(kubectl get sa vault-auth -o jsonpath="{.secrets[*]['name']}")
$ export SA_JWT_TOKEN=$(kubectl get secret $VAULT_SA_NAME -o jsonpath="{.data.token}" | base64 --decode; echo)
$ export SA_CA_CRT=$(kubectl get secret $VAULT_SA_NAME -o jsonpath="{.data['ca\.crt']}" | base64 --decode; echo) 

# determine Kubernetes master IP address (no https://) via `kubectl cluster-info`
$ export K8S_HOST=<K8S_MASTER_IP>   ----- App cluster ip 

# set VAULT_TOKEN & VAULT_ADDR before next steps
$ vault auth enable kubernetes
$ vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
        token_reviewer_jwt="$SA_JWT_TOKEN" \
        kubernetes_host="https://$K8S_HOST:443" \
        kubernetes_ca_cert="$SA_CA_CRT"
```

How is vault inject setup in application cluster

```
name: AGENT_INJECT_VAULT_ADDR
      value: http://10.LB.LB.38:8200
```

Cluster B ( app cluster )

```
kubectl create serviceaccount vault-auth -n default
-----
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: role-tokenreview-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: vault-auth
  namespace: default

vault auth enable kubernetes
-----------
vault write auth/kubernetes/config kubernetes_host="${K8S_HOST}"   
    kubernetes_ca_cert="${VAULT_SA_CA_CRT}" 
    token_reviewer_jwt="${TR_ACCOUNT_TOKEN}"
-----------
vault secrets enable -path=secret/ kv
-----------
vault policy write myapp-kv-rw - <<EOF
 path "secret/myapp/*" {
 capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list"]
}
--------------
vault write auth/kubernetes/role/myapp-role \
 bound_service_account_names=default \
 bound_service_account_namespaces=default \
 policies=default,myapp-kv-rw \
 ttl=15m
```

Can you Please let me know, If I miss anything ?

Comment: Vault logs - 2020-10-04T16:16:40.034Z [ERROR] auth.kubernetes.auth_kubernetes_d78f6a94: login unauthorized due to: Post "https://Cluster_AppB/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews": dial tcp Cluster_AppB:443: i/o timeout

Comment: Could you provide more information? What GKE versions are you using? What exactly `External Vault` are you using? Can you share some logs?

Comment: Gke cluster verison - 1.16.13-gke.1 ( Vault cluster and application cluster) ---- In vault cluster I am running vault with internal LB.  My logs files -- 
2020-10-05T14:06:26.752Z [ERROR] auth.kubernetes.auth_kubernetes_c78cbc33: login unauthorized due to: Post "https://app_custer_masterip:443/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews": dial tcp app_custer_master_ip:443: i/o timeout ........................It worked fine, when I run vault and application pods on same cluster.

Comment: @PjoterS - I have  added the logs files.

Answer (score 4):

Curious as to which version of k8s you're using. I was having the same issue using `v1.21.1`. I had to add an issuer to the per the docs (https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/kubernetes)

> Kubernetes 1.21+ clusters may require setting the service account issuer to the same value as kube-apiserver's --service-account-issuer flag. This is because the service account JWTs for these clusters may have an issuer specific to the cluster itself, instead of the old default of kubernetes/serviceaccount

like so

```
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
  token_reviewer_jwt="$(cat /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token)" \
  kubernetes_host="https://$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR:443" \
  kubernetes_ca_cert=@/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt \
  issuer="\"test-aks-cluster-dns-d6cbb78e.hcp.uksouth.azmk8s.io\""
```

and the issuer can be obtained by running `kubectl proxy & curl --silent http://127.0.0.1:8001/.well-known/openid-configuration | jq -r .issuer`

Comment: I was working on this for hours - you finally provided a solution that wasn't incorrect!!!   Thank you!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to manually access the Kubernetes API (in your app cluster) from your Vault cluster with the same configuration you used to setup Vault.

```
curl -X "POST" "${K8S_HOST}/apis/authentication.k8s.io/v1/tokenreviews" \
     --cacert <(echo $VAULT_SA_CA_CRT)
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer ${TR_ACCOUNT_TOKEN}' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8' \
     -d $'{
  "kind": "TokenReview",
  "apiVersion": "authentication.k8s.io/v1",
  "spec": {
    "token": "${INTERNAL_APP_TOKEN}"
  }
}'
```

If that doesn't work, Vault won't be able to call the API to get the tokens reviewed. If you get a connection timed out or refused, it's most likely a firewall issue. If you get unauthorized, your cluster role setup is probably wrong.

Comment: after using curl command - I am getting -----------------------------------------------------------------
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:internal-app\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403

Comment: You are using the wrong token. "forbidden: User system:serviceaccount:default:internal-app cannot get path /". It's not the internal-app service account that should do the token review, it's the vault-auth service account that should do it.

Comment: I still get the same error msg - message": "forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:vault-auth\" cannot get path \"/\"", ---------

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the path to the token review endpoint, try that and see if you still are getting Forbidden.