# Spring Cloud Vault with GCP-IAM Auth Method for multiple projects

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, spring-vault, vault

I have some issue, wasn't able to find any docs, maybe I'm missing something.

We are going to use [this method](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.authentication.gcpiam). I've deployed some service and Vault in GKE in one project and it works fine. I used [this article](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/gcp) for configuration.
So, I created separate roles in Vault for each project and bound it to workload identity services of each application. Role for service in another project has bound_projects variable with the name of the project.

When I try to login or try to run application in another project, it shows such errors in console:
[RequestedSecret [path='secret/**secret_path**', mode=ROTATE]] Lease [leaseId='null', leaseDuration=PT0S, renewable=false] Cannot login using GCP-IAM: could not find service account 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/<**service_name**>': googleapi: Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.get is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/<**service_name**>., forbidden; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 Internal Server Error: [{"errors":["could not find service account 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/<**service_name**>': googleapi: Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.get is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/<**service_name**>., forbidden"]}
]

When I try to login in console via this sa I got this. I have this user and role with this permission attached to it:

$ vault login -method=gcp     role="my-iam-role-preprod"     service_account="sa_name"     project="project_id"     jwt_exp="15m"     credentials=@cred.json
Error authenticating: Error making API request.

URL: PUT <vault_addr>/v1/auth/gcp/login
Code: 500. Errors:

- could not find service account 'projects/-/serviceAccounts/sa_name': googleapi: Error 403: Permission iam.serviceAccounts.get is required to perform this operation on service account projects/-/serviceAccounts/sa_name., forbidden

I have Service Account Token Creator role assigned to SA in another project and have Browser // Service Account Key Admin roles assigned to Vault service account in project, where Vault is deployed.

Vault version is Vault v1.7.3.
GKE is 1.19.10-gke.1600.

Comment: First, I would suggest to share more information about your configuration. Please could you share Vault's related configuration? We could follow some possible root causes suggested on [similar question about Vault in GKE permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64193339/permission-denied-when-authenticating-pod-to-external-vault-service-running-on-g).

Comment: I took a look at link you shared, but I don't use kubernetes authentication, I use [GCP-IAM](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/reference/html/#vault.config.authentication.gcpiam).
Shared configuration in another answer to this post.